# Откуда серая линия между блоками?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Иногда появляется серая линия между 2 блоками. При увеличении и уменьшении масштаба она исчезает. При обновлении тоже. Появляется, но редко. Кто знает почему? Использую HTML и CSS, JS нету.

```
<div id="block1">
                    <div id="stack-pane-black">
                        <div id="intro-blocks">


                            <div id="block1-text">
                                    <h1 id="caption" class="caption-company">Chessman</h1>
                                    <h3 class="caption-company">Мы смотрим в будущее</h3>
                            </div>

                            <div id="block1-buttons">
                                <div id="chessman-work">
                                    <div class="gardient-buttons">
                                        <div class="text-circle-button">
                                            <h5 class="text-in-cell-conf">Chessman work</h5>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="personnel-reserve">
                                    <div class="gardient-buttons">
                                        <div class="text-circle-button">
                                            <h5 class="text-in-cell-conf">Personnel reserve</h5> 
                                        </div> 
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="selection-of-personnel">
                                    <div class="gardient-buttons">
                                        <div class="text-circle-button">
                                            <h5 class="text-in-cell-conf">Selection of personnel</h5>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>          
                </div>
```

Вот css:

```
#block1 {

            overflow:hidden;
            display: flex;
            margin: auto;
            width: 100%;

            border-radius: 3px;

            height: calc(1100px * 0.5335);
            background-image: url("ImageGlobal2.png");
            background-position: center center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
        }

            #stack-pane-black {
                display: flex;
                margin: auto;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.70); /* Old Browsers */
                background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right,rgba(0,0,0, 0.60),transparent); /*Safari 5.1-6*/
                background: -o-linear-gradient(to right,rgba(0,0,0, 0.60),transparent); /*Opera 11.1-12*/
                background: -moz-linear-gradient(to right,rgba(0,0,0, 0.60),transparent); /*Fx 3.6-15*/
                background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0, 0.60), transparent); /*Standard*/
            }

                #intro-blocks {
                    display: block;
                    margin: auto;

                    width:100%;
                    height: 100%;

/*                    background-image: url("LineLeft.png");
                    background-position: center center;
                    background-repeat: no-repeat;
                    background-size: cover;*/

                }

                    #block1-text {
                        margin: auto;
                        display: block;
                        width: 73.5%;
                        height: 50%;
                    }

                    #caption {padding-top: 85px;}

                            .caption-company {
                                margin: auto;
                                text-align: left;
                                font-weight: 100;
                                color: white;
                            }

                    #block1-buttons {
                        margin-left: auto;
                        margin-right: auto;
                        display: flex;
                        width:80%;
                        height: 50%;
                    }

                        .gardient-buttons {
                            display: flex;
                            margin: auto;

                            width: 100%;
                            height: 100%;

                            background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.60); /* Old Browsers */
                            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom,rgba(0,0,0, 0.60),transparent); /*Safari 5.1-6*/
                            background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom,rgba(0,0,0, 0.60),transparent); /*Opera 11.1-12*/
                            background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom,rgba(0,0,0, 0.60),transparent); /*Fx 3.6-15*/
                            background: linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0, 0.60), transparent); /*Standard*/
                        }

                        .gardient-buttons:hover {
                            background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.80); /* Old Browsers */
                            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom,rgba(0,0,0, 0.70),rgba(0,0,0, 0.08)); /*Safari 5.1-6*/
                            background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom,rgba(0,0,0, 0.70),rgba(0,0,0, 0.08)); /*Opera 11.1-12*/
                            background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom,rgba(0,0,0, 0.70),rgba(0,0,0, 0.08)); /*Fx 3.6-15*/
                            background: linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0, 0.70), rgba(0,0,0, 0.08)); /*Standard*/
                        }

                        .text-circle-button {
                            display: flex;
                            margin: auto;

                            width: 80%;
                            height: 80%;
                        }

                        #chessman-work {
                            overflow: hidden;

                            margin: auto;

                            height: 220px;
                            width: 220px;

                            border-radius: 3px;

                            background-image: url("button1.png");
                            background-position: center center;
                            background-repeat: no-repeat;
                            background-size: cover;

                        }

                        #personnel-reserve {
                            margin: auto;

                            height: 220px;
                            width: 220px;

                            border-radius: 3px;
                            overflow: hidden;

                            background-image: url("button2_2.png");
                            background-position: center center;
                            background-repeat: no-repeat;
                            background-size: cover;
                        }

                        #selection-of-personnel {
                            margin: auto;

                            width: 220px;
                            height: 220px;

                            border-radius: 3px;
                            overflow: hidden;

                            background-image: url("button3.png");
                            background-position: center center;
                            background-repeat: no-repeat;
                            background-size: cover;
                        }
```

Comment: обычно гадают [здесь](https://otvet.mail.ru/chiromancy/) а вот на stackoverflow принято показывать код

Comment: скорее всего хром глючит, если намека на линию эту в коде нет.

Comment: Вам следует показать код, как уже сказано выше, чтобы получить обоснованный ответ. Имея такую проблему, я бы постоветовал проверить, с помощью Dev Tools в браузере, границы каких блоков вашей верстки совпадают с линией. Есть вероятность, что проблема кроется в них. Ну и проверьте страницу в нескольких браузерах.

Comment: @Max Martynov
Вот обновил, но не думаю что код вам поможет.

Comment: Вы получаете серую линию на стыке блоков `#block1-text` &
`#block1-buttons`. К сожалению я не могу проверить Ваш код в IE, так что однозначного ответа дать не могу. У вас есть мелкие недочеты в верстке, так что я бы на вашем месте попробовал сверстать все с нуля - так часто можно выявить ошибку в своем коде, когда все кажется правильным. И советую изучить как устроены сетки в фреймворках. Для примера можете посмотреть [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) или подобные ему.

Comment: @Max Martynov да ладно? а я не знал что у меня линия между #block1-text & #block1-buttons , спасибо ты очень помог. Идика давай советуй вот  [сюда](https://otvet.mail.ru/). Тебе еще рано тут ошиваться.

Comment: На здоровье. Я сожалею, что потратил свое время.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в браузере Microsoft EDGE. В других все нормально. Баг браузера.. Надеюсь исправят.